# Is there a way to achieve both reading process's OutputStream and redirecting it's output to standard io?

Tags: java, processbuilder

I failed to do both reading from process's OutputStream and redirecting it to standard io at the same time. I can do any one of the above, but not both.
I tried to use both `inheritIO()` and `redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)` and it didn't work, I can read the output but it didn't appear in the standard output.

```
  @Test
  void testRedirectOutput() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // when
    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder()
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .inheritIO()
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .command("where", "where")
        .start();
    proc.waitFor();

    // then
    String output = readAllOutput(proc);
    assertNotNull(output);
  }

  private static String readAllOutput(Process process) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    do {
      line = reader.readLine();
      builder.append(line);
    }
    while (line != null);
    reader.close();

    return builder.toString();
  }
```

If I remove `.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)`, it appears on the standard io but I can't read it (`output`=`null`).
Is there an elegant way to achieve it rather than calling `System.out.println(output)`?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain what you're looking for. Does [this](https://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/need-to-write-same-content-to-multiple.html) help?

Comment: I'm writing an end-to-end test for my CLI program, I use ProcessBuilder to invoke my program with some options/arguments. While running the test in Intellj, I want to see the output of my CLI program in the "Run" window, as well as be able to read its output to a string and assert it.
I'm looking for a way to do it with ProcessBuilder, but the link you provided helps in some way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A `Process` runs in parallel to your Java program. While it runs, it reads something from standard input and writes something to standard output and standard error. Typically, a process does **not** read all input at once and then write all output at once. Instead, it reads some input, does something with it, and then produces some output. This repeats itself until the process detects end of input, at which point it writes the remaining output to the standard output and closes it. In such cases, if you tried to write everything at once and then read everything at once, the OS buffers would fill up and your streams would become blocked in read/write operation.

This means you need a separate `Thread` to handle each stream. In addition to the thread that is running this code (probably `main`), you will need two other threads. If the input and output can fit into memory, you can simply pass the data around as `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` to corresponding threads, and let them do the "pumping" of the data to/from the process.